# Проблема с удаление файлов в только что созданном React проекте

Tags: reactjs

Можете подсказать, почему вылетает такая ошибка? Это только что созданный проект react с удаленными файлами и импортами, которые обращались к ним.
Строки и файлы, к которым обращается ошибка отсутствуют в проекте и терминалу это почему-то не нравится, хотя импортов нет.
Кеш, что в браузере, что в npm чистил.

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 4:0-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in      

ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:0-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './index.css' in

ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import TodoForm from './components/TodoForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <TodoForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Покажите что у вас в /src/App.js и /src/index.js в первых 10 строках. Если ругается, значит там стоит импорт

Comment: @SwaD ошибка выглядит как фантомная боль, так что я даже не знаю, что делать.

Comment: Вопрос: а вы эти файлы сохранили на диске? Может ваша IDE не сохранила изменения в файлах, а физически нужные файлы уже удалены. Один из вариантов, все закрыть и заново открыть.

Comment: @SwaD да, мне тоже кажется, будто IDE не меняет состояние проекта при его изменениях, но я для этого ничего не делал. В остальном, компьютер уже перегружал, IDE перезапускал, проект с 0 создавал. Результат тот же. Изначально думал, что дело в корзине, но в итоге она сейчас пуста, а IDE всё еще ищет призрачные файлы, которые нигде не используются.

Comment: @SwaD и я пользуюсь VS Code, у него стоит автосохранение каждую секунду. Так что я уже очень давно не делал никакие сохранения самостоятельно.

Comment: попробуйте удалить, например index.js и посмотреть, что будет. если ошибка останется, то возможно, вы меняете не тот файл

Comment: @SwaD всё нормализовалось, спасибо. Я недавно переустанавливал систему и думал, что все-все настройки vscode восстановились, а на деле оказалось, что только расширения. Автосохранения действительно стали выключенными. Так что всё оказалось проще, чем думалось.